# 70s (or earlier) children's sci-fi novel with tiny intelligent gemstones falling from the sky, a kid forms a mental connection with them

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I'm trying to remember the name of a (children's?) sci-fi novel I read as a child in the mid-80s, but it might have been written in the 1970s or earlier.

It was about tiny coloured gemstones that fell from the sky all over a city. Two/three young friends collected some up, then discovered the gemstones were intelligent. The gemstones would connect together to form different shapes and spell out words. One of the friends, I think, formed some sort of mental connection with the stones and could manipulate them.

Have searched for it online but can't find anything that fits my recollection.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's [*Trillions*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1087689.Trillions) by [Nicholas Fisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Fisk), which is indeed from the 1970s.

> Trillions were hard, bright, tiny things which suddenly arrived, millions and millions and millions of them, one windy day in a village called Harbourtown.
>
> No one could explain them, much less why they had suddenly arrived. Were they a blessing, as their beauty suggested, or a deadly, inexplicable threat?

Comment: Wow, yes! Thank you! That has been bothering me for years! Of to track it down now!